# How to implement tree with self join table in Laravel 5.2

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-5

I need a tree in my project. I have a table named category and it has a foriegn key to its id. The eloquent code for making this table is:

```
 Schema::create('categories', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->unsignedInteger('category_id')->nullable();
        $table->string('title');
        $table->timestamps();

        $this->foreign('category_id')
            ->references('id')
            ->on('categories')
            ->onDelete('cascade');
    });
```

There is many problem here:
1. Error in migrate:

> PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined method
>   CreateCategoriesTable::foreign()

2. How to alias tables so i can do this query:

   ```
   SELECT *
   FROM categories sub
   LEFT JOIN categories parent ON parent.id = sub.category_id
   ```
3. Is there any way to define this relation on category model like:

   ```
   public function parent()
   {
       return $this->belongsTo(Category::class);
   }
   ```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First problem:

```
$this->foreign('category_id') to
$table->foreign('category_id')
```

Second problem:

```
\DB::table('categories as sub')->leftJoin('categories as parent', 'parent.id','=','sub.category_id')->get();
```

Thrid problem:

```
return $this->belongsTo(Category::class, 'id', 'parent_id');
```